# drawer menu fonts are not changed programatically

Tags: android

My code is shown below:

```
public class QuFlipActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initNavigationDrawer();

....

}

public void initNavigationDrawer() {

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        overrideFonts(QuFlipActivity.this, navigationView);
....
}

public static void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Consts.montserrat_regular);
        try {
            if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
                for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                    overrideFonts(context, child);
                }
            } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(typeface);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Now, here even If I write the code to change the default fonts, it is not able to change it, what modifications can I make to make it work?

Comment: Where is `QuFlipActivity` defined?

Comment: I have updated the question in which I have mentioned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem and I solved it by changing the font inside a Runnable. Try to call the override font function like below and see if it works for you

```
navigationView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        overrideFonts(QuFlipActivity.this, navigationView);
    }
});
```